# Why is a reference leaked from inside a lambda despite using clone?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement the clone_into_box pattern in a piece of code the uses callbacks, and I'm running into an error I'm having trouble understanding.

Basically, I'm cloning the parameter of a lambda, but the borrow checker still complains I'm leaking a reference to said parameter.

My question: is this a case of the borrow checker being overly conservative (and if so, how can I re-write this in a way that would play nicely with the borrow checker), or is there something I'm missing here and a reference is indeed being leaked despite the clone?

Code:

```
pub trait CloneIntoBox{
    fn clone_into_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneIntoBox + 'a>;
}

impl<'a> Clone for Box<dyn CloneIntoBox + 'a> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.as_ref().clone_into_box()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct StructWithBox<'a> {
    pub my_box: Box<dyn CloneIntoBox + 'a>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct StructThatCanBeClonedIntoBox {
    pub data: u32,
}

impl CloneIntoBox for StructThatCanBeClonedIntoBox {
    fn clone_into_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneIntoBox + 'a> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

pub type WalkCallback<'a> = dyn FnMut(&StructWithBox) + 'a;

pub fn walk(data: Vec<u32>, cb: &mut WalkCallback) {
    for d in data{
        let instance = StructWithBox{my_box: Box::new(StructThatCanBeClonedIntoBox{data:d})};
        cb(&instance);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2];
    let mut result = vec![];
    walk(data, &mut|param| result.push((*param).clone()));
}
```

[[Playground link]](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80768178088472499d13667f577b5ec2)

Gives:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
  --> src/main.rs:39:28
   |
38 |     let mut result = vec![];
   |         ---------- `result` declared here, outside of the closure body
39 |     walk(data, &mut|param| result.push((*param).clone()));
   |                     -----  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `param` escapes the closure body here
   |                     |
   |                     `param` is a reference that is only valid in the closure body
```

Comment: Nitpick: `(*param).clone()` -> `param.clone()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `'a` in `StructWithBox`. Consider the following implementation of `walk()`:

```rust
impl<'b> CloneIntoBox for &'b u32 {
    fn clone_into_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneIntoBox + 'a> {
        Box::new(&42)
    }
}

pub fn walk(data: Vec<u32>, cb: &mut WalkCallback) {
    let data = 123u32;
    let instance = StructWithBox {
        my_box: Box::new(&data),
    };
    cb(&instance);
}
```

I haven't found a way to make this actually unsound: the only thing you can return from the `impl CloneIntoBox for &u32` is a `'static` reference, since `'a` is decided by the caller. But the borrow checker doesn't know that: it assumes that `'a` can be any lifetime in the callback, and then we push it into the vector outside the callback, but it can be freed after the callback is finished. So you can consider this overly conservative, or not.

To fix that you can make `'a` always `'static` in the callback:

```rust
pub type WalkCallback<'a> = dyn FnMut(&StructWithBox<'static>) + 'a;
```

Or get rid of the lifetime altogether:

```rust
pub trait CloneIntoBox {
    fn clone_into_box(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneIntoBox>;
}

impl Clone for Box<dyn CloneIntoBox> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.as_ref().clone_into_box()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct StructWithBox {
    pub my_box: Box<dyn CloneIntoBox>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct StructThatCanBeClonedIntoBox {
    pub data: u32,
}

impl CloneIntoBox for StructThatCanBeClonedIntoBox {
    fn clone_into_box(&self) -> Box<dyn CloneIntoBox> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```rust
pub type WalkCallback<'a> = dyn FnMut(&StructWithBox) + 'a;
```

is equivalent to to

```rust
pub type WalkCallback<'a> = dyn for<'b> FnMut(&StructWithBox<'b>) + 'a;
```

which requires the callback to be able to take a `StructWithBox` of any lifetime `'c`, as long as it is alive when the callback is called. Since the `StructWithBox` may not be valid any longer than that, it can't be pushed to a vector that lives longer than the callback.

Changing this to

```rust
pub type WalkCallback<'a, 'b> = dyn FnMut(&StructWithBox<'b>) + 'a;
```

allows the callback to only accept lifetimes longer than `'b`.
In this case, `'b` is inferred to be as long as `result` lives for, so that `StructWithBox<'b>` can be pushed to `result`.